# Executing two separate queries in one repository method, one after the other using dapper, is there a better way to do this?

Tags: c#, sql, repository-pattern

I'm trying to retrieve the county name from the county table but I don't have the countyID only the countyOfficeId, which is in the CountyOfficeTable.  So I'm using the countyOfficeId to grap the CountyId from the County Table, then looking up the county using that CountyId. is there a better way to do this?

```
public CountyDto GetCountyByCountyOfficeId(int countyOfficeId)
        {
            int countyMatch;
            const string sql = "Select CountyID from CountyOffice WHERE CountyOfficeID = @countyOfficeId";

            using (var conn = _connFactory.CreateSqlConnectionForTrhGlobal())
            {
                countyMatch =  conn.QueryFirstOrDefault<int>(sql, new { countyOfficeId });
            }

            //Now use CountyID to retrieve the county for that office
            const string sqlTwo = "Select * from County WHERE CountyID = @countyID";

            using (var conn = _connFactory.CreateSqlConnectionForTrhGlobal())
            {
                return conn.QueryFirstOrDefault<CountyDto>(sql, new { countyMatch});
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but if you need to run two queries, there's no need to use two connections. You can run one query right after the first is complete using the same connection. The performance penalty of using two connections may be negligible thank to connection pooling, but it's not as efficient as using the already-open connection.

Answer (score 3):

Use SQL to join the two tables.

```
public CountyDto GetCountyByCountyOfficeId(int countyOfficeId)
{
    const string sql = @"
    SELECT c.*
    FROM County c
    JOIN CountyOffice co ON c.CountyID = co.CountyID
    WHERE co.CountyOfficeId = @countyOfficeId
    "@;

    using (var conn = _connFactory.CreateSqlConnectionForTrhGlobal())
    {
        return conn.QueryFirstOrDefault<CountyDto>(sql, new { countyOfficeId });
    }
}
```